# Detecting if ANY window is being dragged

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, core-graphics, nsevent

Is there a way (without using any undocumented API) to figure out if ANY window (not just the application from which the code is running from) is being dragged?

I can use

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:]
```

but this is just for general dragging and there's no way to tell if a window is beign dragged or not.

Thanks!

Update: I think the answer might lie with these two functions: 
CGSGetWindowBounds
CGSNewRegionWithData
If someone can tell me what these functions do and where I can find the documentation for them, it would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your only viable, system-supported API is the [Accessibility Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXModel/OSXAXmodel.html). You can get [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXModel/OSXAXmodel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001078-CH208-TPXREF107) this way for other applications' windows but access to read/modify is limited to position/size.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if there's a better approach, but here's one way to do it:

Create an `BOOL` ivar that tracks whether a window is being moved or not. Then register for the `NSWindowWillMoveNotification` and `NSWindowDidMoveNotication` notifications:

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowWillMove:) name:NSWindowWillMoveNotification object:nil];
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidMove:) name:NSWindowDidMoveNotification object:nil];
```

Then handle the notifications and set the ivar appropriately:

```
- (void)windowWillMove:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    windowBeingDragged = YES;
}

- (void)windowDidMove:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    windowBeingDragged = NO;
}
```

Now you can just check the value of the ivar (`windowBeingDragged` in this case, to check if a window is being dragged).

Comment: Thanks for the input. But these notifications are for windows owned by the application...I was asking about windows from ANY applications.

Comment: Whoops, sorry I missed that part. In that case I'm not sure.